# Loop for repeating statement

Tags: vba, excel

I need to write a Loop to run the following lines until the third line finds the cell it is selecting to be empty.

I would normally include my code for the loop to be corrected / critiqued but after searching all morning I can't find an example of do while loop that doesn't count to keep moving.

Can someone point me in the right direction with a link or two?

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Selection.Offset(0, 3).Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection(1, 3)).Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Output").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.Offset(1, 1).Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False

'Include Fund name
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Output").Select
Range("B2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select

Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False


Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Offset(0, -1).Select
Selection.FillDown
```

Answer (score 1):

*I can't find an example of do while loop that doesn't count to keep moving.*

You didn't look very hard, then. All `Do` or `While` loops should have a terminator, or an `Exit` statement, otherwise they will crash the application in an infinite loop.

Try:

```
 Do Until Sheets("Sheet1").Selection.Offset(1, 0).Value = vbNullString

    '// YOUR CODE HERE //


 Loop
```

Or:

```
Do
   If Sheets("Sheet1").Selection.Offset(1, 0).Value = vbNullString Then Exit Do

   '// YOUR CODE HERE //

Loop
```

Comment: My apologies, but I don't know enough VBA to know what most of this code means.

I will experiment and review, and attempt not to waste time anyone's time in the future.